# Javascript highlight and link url - Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, hyperlink

I currently have a table that I am using to list a series of jobs in my RoR application like so:

```
<section id="table-wrapper">
  <table id="jobs">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>position</td>
        <td>company</td>
        <td>location</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <% @jobs.each do |job| %>
        <%= link_to url_with_protocol(job.job_url), :target => '_blank' do %>
          <tr>
            <td><strong><%= job.title %></strong></td>
            <td><%= job.company %></td> 
            <td><%= job.city %>, <%= job.country %></td>
          </tr>
        <% end %>           
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</section>
```

What I would like to happen is that when the user hovers over the table row the font changes colour and when they click on the row they are sent to the Job URL that is currently being passed through by job.job_url method.

What I can't work out is how to get this to integrat with Javascript?

Any advice and help people have on this would be much appreciated :)

Updated Content

```
#JS
$('table tbody tr').click(function(){
  <%= link_to job.job_url, :target => '_blank' do %>;
})


#HTML
<section id="table-wrapper">
  <table id="jobs">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>position</td>
        <td>company</td>
        <td>location</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <% @jobs.each do |job| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= job.title %></td>
          <td><%= job.company %></td>   
          <td><%= job.city %>, <%= job.country %></td>
        </tr>       
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</section>
```

This still doesn't seem to be working - do you know where I am going wrong?

Comment: you can interact with the javascript through the class, id and html attributes. What's your exact problem here?

Comment: Hi Vinay, I am looking to highlight the text and link the entire row (tr, not td) on user hover and click using javascript. However because it's Ruby I need to be able to pass the Job.job_url into the href element generated by the javascript. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use css to change the font weight of the row using `:hover` selector.  As for the link, you can add a `data-url` attribute and add some js which observes click events

```
# css
table tr:hover { font-size: 100px; }

# js
$('table tr').click(function() { window.location = $(this).data('url') })

# html
<table>
  <tr data-url='http://google.com'>
    <td>...</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

UPDATE: html using job.job_url

assuming you have the list of jobs on `@jobs`

```
<table>
  <% @jobs.each do |job| %>
    <tr data-url='<%= job.job_url %>'>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

UPDATE: use `href` instead of `data-url` (there might be some legacy issues when trying to use data-url)

**The final working answer for this was:**

```
$ ->
  $('tr[href]').click -> window.open 'http://' + $(this).attr('href');
```

Comment: Hi Jvnil, Thanks for your answer. Do you know how I would pass job.job_url into the $(this).data('url') part of the javascript so that the JS uses the link that is stored in my DB? Cheers

Comment: Hey Jvnil, I tried the data-url= setup but can't seem to get it to work.  I have updated my code with how it looks now, it is the link I am most concerned to get correct. Do you know how I can amend to make it work? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: hi Tom, try to copy my second table (just replace the td) and change your js to my js. see if that works.

Comment: Hey, still no joy unfortunately it all formats correctly but when I click a row nothing happens. Do I need to put something before or after that single line of Javascript to get it use javascript as I literally have that line at the moment? Cheers